# Writing nested loops in Python correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a loop that pulls people's Twitter followers. Because Twitter only returns 5K followers at a time, this loop should repeat for each user until it gets all the followers. And because sometimes Twitter returns errors randomly, it should also re-try a few times in case of failure.

Here's my current attempt, which produces an infinite loop, and I don't know how to fix it. I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way to write it, I just don't know what it is.

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(access_token_key, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret))

next_cursor=-1
while next_cursor!=0:
    for _ in range(5):
        count=1
        try:
            twitter_pull=t.followers.ids(user_id=some_id,cursor=next_cursor)
            followers_list=twitter_pull['ids']
            next_cursor=twitter_pull['next_cursor']
            if next_cursor!=0:
                time.sleep(60)
            break
        except Exception:
            print("Something went wrong: ", Exception)
            count=count+1
            if count>=5:
                break
        time.sleep(120)
```

I know there are a bunch of questions on nested loops, but after reading the answers to them, I could not figure out how to solve my problem.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, please fix it

Comment: Why do you need the `count` variable? Isn't that what `for _ in range(5):` does?

Comment: Thanks, Alex, just fixed it. Barmar, initially I started without a count variable, but then when I got an exception, Python went into an infinite loop. So the count variable was my attempt to break it out of the loop, but it clearly didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides no way to break directly from multiple loops.

One solution is to embed your nested loops in a specific function and use return:

```
def nested_loop(...):
  while next_cursor != 0:
    for _ in range(5):
       if ...:
         return ...
```

An other solution is to raise a specific exception:

```
class CustomError(Exception): pass

try:
  while next_cursor != 0:
    for _ in range(5):
      if ...:
        raise CustomError
except CustomError:
   ...
```

A last solution is to use continue/break in a tricky way:

```
while next_cursor != 0:
  for _ in range(5):
    if ...:
      break
  else:
    continue

  # Next line is reached only if break is raised in the for loop
  break
```